# Forçar download de vários arquivos gerados dinamicamente com PHPExcel

Tags: php, download, phpexcel

Possuo uma classe responsável por receber o upload de uma ou várias planilhas `.XLS` com muitos dados detalhados (Essa planilha é padrão), e converter em um outro arquivo `.XLS` mais enxugado para impressão.

```
class convertTimeWorkFileSheets {

    public function convert_sheets() {

        $sheets = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {

            $name[$i] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];

            $xls[$i] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];

            $excelReader[$i] = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($xls[$i]);

            $excelReader[$i]->setReadDataOnly();

            $excelReader[$i]->setLoadAllSheets();

            $excelObj[$i] = $excelReader[$i]->load($xls[$i]);

            $row_max[$i] = $excelObj[$i]->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
            $col_name[$i] = $excelObj[$i]->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
            $col_max[$i] = \PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($col_name[$i]);


            for ($row[$i] = 2; $row[$i] <= 83; $row[$i] ++) {
                for ($col[$i] = 1; $col[$i] <= 52; $col[$i] ++) {
                    $colL[$i] = \geralComponents\substrings::subs_numb_by_letter($col[$i]);
                    $sheets[$i][$colL[$i] . $row[$i]] = $excelObj[$i]->getActiveSheet()->getCell($colL[$i] . $row[$i])->getCalculatedValue();
                }
            }

            self::make_sheet($sheets, $name);
        }
    }

    private static function make_sheet($sheets, $name) {
        $a = 0;

        foreach ($sheets as $file) {
            $plan = '';
            $OBJxlsMaker[$a] = new \PHPExcel();
            $OBJxlsMaker[$a]->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            foreach ($file as $cell => $value) {
                if ($cell == 'B2') {
                    $OBJxlsMaker[$a]->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($cell, $value);
                }
                //AQUI É ONDE A PLANILHA NOVA É FEITA, MAS NÃO É AQUI O PROBLEMA
            }
            //O PROBLEMA É AQUI
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$name[$a].'.xls"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

            $writer[$a] = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($OBJxlsMaker[$a], 'Excel5');
            $writer[$a]->save('assets/converteds-xls/'.$name[$a]);

            $a += 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Bom, a planilha é gerada, e salva na pasta `'assets/converteds-xls/'`, mas não consigo forçar o download dessa planilha, substituir a saida por `php:/output` me devolve apenas os atributos do arquivo, nome, tamnho etc.., e tudo desformatado.

Eu preciso gerar os arquivos em quantidade dinamica (funciona), salvar os arquivos indivudualmente (funciona), só não consigo forçar o download de mais de um arquivo na mesma requisição, alguém teria alguma ideia pra fazer isso ?

OBS: Isso não é salvo no banco de dados, apenas recebe o upload, enxuga as informações, e a resposta deve ser o download de todos os arquivos upados de novo.

OBS 2 : A requisição vem via `AJAX`.

OBS 3 : Se eu gerar apenas um unico arquivo, responder com `$writer->save('php://output');` força o download corretamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, não tem como fazer multiplas respostas para uma requisição HTTP:

```
foreach ($sheets as $file) {

    ...

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$name[$a].'.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    ...
}
```

Isso nem faz sentido em como o HTTP funciona, HTTP é requisição e resposta, não múltiplas respostas.

Outra coisa, o Ajax não vai interpretar coisas como:

- `Content-Disposition: attachment`
- `Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel`

O navegador até pode ver como isto, mas o Ajax não vai interagir com o gerenciador de downloads, Ajax é isso, pegar a resposta UNICA HTTP de uma requisição especifica e salvar em uma variavel, e então você decide o que fazer com a resposta.

### Como resolver

Você poderia todos os arquivos gerados em `assets/converteds-xls/` **na requisição atual** e gerar uma resposta pro ajax assim:

```
[
    'assets/converteds-xls/file200.xls',
    'assets/converteds-xls/file201.xls',
    'assets/converteds-xls/file202.xls'
]
```

Deve enviar `Content-type: application/json` se estiver usando jQuery para facilitar o "parse" e então no Ajax fazer isto:

```
function forceDownload(files) {
    var current = 0;

    function trigger() {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = files[current];
        a.download = true;
        a.click();

        current++; //Proximo download

        setTimeout(trigger, 500); //Timeout necessário
    }

    trigger();
}

var jqxhr = $.ajax( "gerarxls.php" ).done(function(xls) {
    forceDownload(xls);
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

### Compactando no back-end

Você também pode compactar os arquivos gerados usando [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php)

```
$caminho = 'assets/converteds-xls/';

$zip = new ZipArchive;

$zipfile = 'pasta_foo_bar/[NOME TEMPORARIO].zip';

$new = $zip->open($zipfile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);

$zip->addFile($caminho . $entry, '[nome do xls].xls');

$zip->close();
```

Se for um servidor Linux pode ser mais eficiente usar `exec`, algo como:

```
exec('tar -czf [NOME TEMPORARIO].tar.gz file1 file2 file3'); //Compacta tar.gz
```

E depois usar `readfile` do PHP para fazer fazer o download do `[NOME TEMPORARIO].tar.gz` ou usar `header('Location: [NOME TEMPORARIO].tar.gz');`, se for Ajax terá que fazer o uso de algo como no .php:

```
echo 'pasta_foo_bar/[NOME TEMPORARIO].tar.gz';
```

E na resposta do Ajax:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "gerarxls.php" ).done(function(resposta) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = resposta; //Resposta que contem a url do compactado
    a.download = true;
    a.click();
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
});
```

Comment: Então é impossível eu forçar mais de um download na mesma requisição de nenhuma forma ?

Comment: @AnthraxisBR não é questão de impossível, é questão de ilógico, ainda mais sendo Ajax, que como expliquei nunca irá fazer o download, no entanto editei a resposta e deixei sugestões de como fazer múltiplos downloads simultaneos.

Comment: É que esse negócio é só uma solução temporária enquanto a parte do sistema que vai fazer esse tramit que agora é feito feito em planilha não fica totalmente estável, não tem problema ser uma 'gambiarra', obrigado!

Comment: @AnthraxisBR não considero as soluções passadas como gambiarra :) ... Mas é claro que tudo pode ser melhorado.